# Raw query in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I'm coming from a PHP background where you create a PDO Object and can query right away.

I have a database from which I extract data which, for example, is a list of Object -> Quantity (Example Items sales). This is part of another application, I'm just writing an app to show some statistics.

I cannot find how to execute a raw query in ASP.Net Core and have a IEnumerable object. All examples use Entity Framework and a model (which I don't have in my current app, because it's full of raw sql queries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute raw SQL like the below (but is prone to injection).

```
using (var context = new SqlConnection())
{
      var cmd = new SqlCommand
      {
          CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table",
          CommandType = CommandType.Text,
          Connection = context
      };

      context.Open();

      var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      reader.Close();
  }
```

I would only do this if you 100% can't use EF and its database/code first techniques.

I updated my answer to ensure that the object is disposed of as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: It's worth noting that SqlConnection, SqlCommand and IDataReader all implement IDisposable, so you should wrap them in usings too

Comment: Thanks. Is this something about ADO.Net?

Comment: I don't think a data reader is enumerable. But this answers half of the question. You could definitely build an enumerable list from the result.

Comment: Scott Perham's comment is a C# thing. Wrapping object creation in using statements ensures that objects that implement the IDisposable interface are properly disposed. If you use the DataReader be careful about disposing the connection object. The DataReader requires an open connection during its lifetime. Not saying don't dispose the connection, just be careful that it is not disposed until you are finished with the DataReader.

Comment: It's prone to injection only if you compose your query string from used input. Using parameters for these values makes it perfectly safe.   /Bobby tables